# While opening VisualStudio it gives me following error

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have installed Visual Studio on my Linux(Ubuntu) machine but while I am opening it gives me error like... 
[image]

Comment: It seems pretty clear what you have to do...

Comment: I have installed visual studio but while opening gives error shown in screenshoot

Answer (score 0):

By deleting the directory `Code` inside `/home/[USERNAME]/.config`, you'll be able to launch VScode again.

---

**Step by step** (replace `USERNAME` by your username):

```
$ cd /home/[USERNAME]/.config

$ sudo rm -rf Code
[enter your password if needed]
```

Then launch VSCode. It might probably take a moment till VSCode shows up, because the deleted folder will be recreated on launch.